# Protractor - If element is displayed/presented

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor

so I have a very weird scenario where I want to add a if-else statement in my code and thats due to:

[image: noCheckbox]
[image: Checkbox]

As you can see, the one with 13:00 has no checkbox while the 16:00 has a checkbox and basically what I want to do is a simple test case which is, click if there is checkbox else we continue to press next step button. meaning...

if we get a checkbox to click on, then we click on the checkbox and then press click next step. IF we don't get any checkbox displayed/presented then we skip it. (We do not need to have a wait function to see if its loading because it will load automatic as soon as I press a specific time (No calls from backend/api) so if I press 16:00 it will imminently pop up the checkbox and vice versa.

```
 it("Has truck and choose first avaliable delivery",
            async function () {
                const nextStep = servicesPage.getForm().buttons.nextStep;
                let lateDelivery = element(by.className("checkbox-label"));

                if (lateDelivery.isPresent()) {
                    console.log("Checkbox")
                    await utils.elementToBeClickable(lateDelivery, "Late hour checkbox should be clickable");
                    await utils.click(lateDelivery);

                }

                console.log("Click")
                await utils.elementToBeClickable(nextStep, "Next step button should be clickable");
                await utils.click(nextStep);
            })
```

What is happening even if I do have isPresent() it still seems to go inside the if-statement even though when I check through the page, there is no `element(by.className("checkbox-label"))` presented at all on the webpage. it does come whenever I press a time after 16:00. What can I do to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lateDelivery.isPresent()
```

returns a promise which is `defined` thats why its true.

Synchronize your code like

```
const isPresent = await lateDelivery.isPresent()
if (isPresent) {
// code
}
```

or resolve it

```
lateDelivery.isPresent().then(res => {
   if (res) {
   // code
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh lord, was it actually that quite simple... I did the first code and it worked actually as I wanted to! Really appreciate it!